# Type mismatch in argument from adding -fdefault-real-16 flag?

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

If I compile the following code without the `-fdefault-real-16` flag in gfortran I have no error from the compiler:

```
SUBROUTINE SUB(ARGUMENTS)
*     ..
*     .. Local Scalars ..
      COMPLEX*16         CDUM
*     ..
*     .. Intrinsic Functions ..
      INTRINSIC          ABS, DBLE, DIMAG, MAX
*     ..
*     .. Statement Functions ..
      DOUBLE PRECISION   CABS1
*     ..
*     .. Statement Function definitions ..
      CABS1( CDUM ) = ABS( DBLE( CDUM ) ) + ABS( DIMAG( CDUM ) )
* More subroutine stuff *
END
```

However, as soon as a I `-fdefault-real-16` I get:

```
3059 |       CABS1( CDUM ) = ABS( DBLE( CDUM ) ) + ABS( DIMAG( CDUM ) )
     |                                                        1
Error: In call to 'dimag' at (1), type mismatch in argument 'z'; pass 'COMPLEX(8)' to 'COMPLEX(16)'
```

What?  `CDUM` is explicitly declared as a `COMPLEX*16` in the declarations section, why would it cause a problem?

My full compile line is:

```
gfortran -fno-align-commons -finit-local-zero -g -c -O0 -ffpe-trap=zero,overflow,underflow -std=legacy -fallow-argument-mismatch -march=native myfile.f
```

**Update for comments:** The situation is, this one error is one of many in a 20k-line .f file, which is itself part of a 200k+ code base from the late 80s that I'm trying to get to run on a modern machine.  I am aware that there are a lot of dangerous options in my compile line (e.g. `-finit-local-zero` and `-fallow-argument-mismatch`) that I would certainly prefer not to use if it weren't for the fact that the mere existence of this code-base is an assault on standard FORTRAN coding practices.  I honestly have no idea how this code ever ran but it did and I'm trying to figure out what special combination code modifications and compiler flags will replicate the environment whatever retired engineer was using 30 years ago.

The reason why I'm using `-fdefault-real-16` is because it solved issues with one of the 57 other source files having inconsistencies with their data alignment.  I'm not just adding flags willy-nilly, there are reasons for all of them (e.g. there are literally hundreds of places in the code where local variables get used without being initialized first)

The reasons I'm confused is because the error says `pass 'COMPLEX(8)' to 'COMPLEX(16)'`, which to me says the compiler thinks I'm trying to pass a `COMPLEX(8)`-typed variable into a `COMPLEX(16)` function.

I guess what's really happening, is that the function expects a `COMPLEX(8)` when it's getting passed a `COMPLEX(16)`, though that is very much not what the message says.  This is happening because while the variable itself is a 16-byte complex variable (since it was declared with `COMPLEX*16`) it doesn't have `KIND=16` by default until I add the flag, so after I added the flag the compiler added the `KIND` label, which meant the compiler recognized it was getting a 16-byte `COMPLEX` as input to `DIMAG`, which shouldn't happen but apparently does with this code-base.

I guess what I need to do now is change all those D- intrinsic functions so they match the data type that's actually being passed to them.

Comment: `dimag` is a specifc intrinsic function.  It takes a `complex(8)` argument.  You used an option that you don't understand, so you are now trying to pass a `complex(16)` entity to a function that isn't expecting it.  The error message even tells you what you have done.

Comment: Are you using `-fdefault-real-16` or `-fdefault-real-8`?  Either way, why use a specific function rather than the generic, where you don't need to worry about matching types? (And to quote [another answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69061917/3157076) "Compiler options like `-fdefault-integer-8` are not toys.")

Comment: There's an interesting question here around what (the horrible, non-standard) `complex*16` means with gfortran, and its relation to real kinds and such compiler options, so please give as much detail in the question as to what you think is happening. (So we can fill in gaps without covering lots of basic material.)

Comment: I would explicitly add that `COMPLEX*16` is not the same as `COMPLEX(16)`. They are not compatible at all.

Comment: I would also **very strongly** recommend against any flags which change the default kinds such as `-fdefault-real-16`, they open a can of worms and you are just asking for a life of pain. Write the properly code to use the data type you require, don't hack it with compiler flags. `-finit-local-zero` is as bad, as well. Note also specific intrinsic functions were all but superseded by generic ones almost half a century ago.

Comment: As the person who implemented the `-fdefault-real-*` options in gfortran, I think you may not understand what that option is doing.   If the code is crufty old pile of garbage, you're likely looking for the `-std=legacy` option.

Comment: @steve Note that `-std=legacy` is in my compile line :).  The more I work with this code, the more I have no idea how it ever worked. I'm probably going to take out the `-fdefault-*` option.

Comment: @steve Also, as I understand `-f-default-real-*` changes the byte-size/precision of `REAL`s declared with no type specified?  I didn't understand the distinction between `type`s and `REAL*<size>` specifiers, but TIL the CL option is imputing the `(TYPE=<size>)` on all `REAL`s not otherwise specified, correct?

Comment: Is the code available to others?  If you want to force everything to use a single real type, you can do so by adding `-freal-4-real-8 -freal-10-real-8 -freal-16-real-8`.  This might cause issue if the code uses `equivalence`.  As far as the `D` functions, simply convert them to generic intrinsic functions, e.g., `DIMAG` becomes `AIMAG`.  The compiler then choose the right intrinsic routine.

Comment: @steve I don't want to force anything, I want to make it so whatever assumptions the original programmers were operating under 30+ years ago when they implicitly defined thousands of variables matches the default variable sizes

Comment: Well, 30 years ago, I doubt the original author was using real(10) and real(16).  Forcing everything to `real(8)` aka `real*8` aka `double precision` will likely get you past some issues.  You didn't answer fmy first question.  Is the code available to others?  Ian and Vladimir and francescalus and few others are fairly sharp tools.

Comment: @steve Sorry, thought I'd answered it but didn't add the submit button.  Code is proprietary, no sharing.

Comment: The thought occurred to me while I was considering this issue later--does `COMPLEX*16` actually map to `COMPLEX(8)` or `COMPLEX(16)`?  Now that I understand the difference between `kind` and size specifiers more, I'm betting it's the former because a `COMPLEX*16` is basically two `REAL*8`'s mushed together, right?